# Resizable Div Horizontally, Update Height

Tags: html, resizable

Read stackoverflow loads and it has rescued me countless times! :)  I need some help though if possible for the following:

I have a div called wrap1 that has a resize feature on it and this works horizontal only

inside this div is another div that has the content.

What i need is for the wrap1 to only be if they make it smaller than the width of the content then it automatically increases the height of the div so it doesnt go outside the wrap1 div (at present it is forcing it down onto second line correctly but div height is a wrong

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery('#wrap1').draggable().resizable({handles:
>   'e, w,ne,nw,se,sw', resize:
>   function(event, ui) { 
>   $(this).css('height', 'auto'); }  });

that code made it draggable and then in resize it updated the div height :)

We also got the resize boxes to imlement by appending html code into the wrap1 div...then on deselect it removed this code